# Find sub vector space and function $f$ such that $\cal A=f+U:=\{f+u\mid u\in U\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $V=\mathbb R[t]_{\le 3}$ and $\cal A=\{p\in V \mid p(-1)=4 \land p(1)=6\}$.
Show or disprove that $\cal A$ is a vector space. My approach: Let $p(x)=5+x$ and $q(x)=5+x^3$. Then $\cal A$ is not closed under addition, since $p,q\in \cal A, $ but $(p+q)(1)=p(1)+q(1)=(5+1)+(5+1)=12 \ne 6$. Thus $p+q\notin \cal A$.

I guess this attempt is okay, or?

Now I am looking for a polynom $f\in V$ and a vector subspace $\cal U$, such that $\cal A=f+U:=\{f+u\mid u\in U\}$.
I do not know how to handle this here. I thought to take $f=p=5+x$, but this does not work I guess. Some help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes,  it does work! $U$ is the subspace of polynomials vanishing at $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @Helmut thanks for your help, can you give a formal definition of $U$?

Comment: You have $\cal A=p+U$, where $p=5+x$ and $U=\{g\in V\mid g(-1)=0\land g(1)=0\}$. $U$ is a subspace. For example $q-p=x^3-x$ is in $U$.